# How to multiply the sampling of 4 rolling dice?

Tags: r

This is what I have done so far:

Input:

```
X <- 1:6

Y <- sample(X, 4, replace = T)

print(Y)
```

Output:

```
> X <- 1:6
> Y <- sample(X, 4, replace = T)
> print(Y)

    [1] 5 3 1 4
```

pleas help me with multiplication of four numbers that I obtained

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Do you want the product of the four numbers, e.g. `prod(y)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code that gives a data.frame with the result of each dice and their product.

```
library(tidyverse)

# 100 replications of the 4 dices
replicate(n = 100,expr =  sample(1:6, 4, replace = TRUE),simplify = TRUE) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as_tibble() %>%
  #Multiplicate each of the dices 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(prod = prod(c_across()))


# A tibble: 100 x 5
# Rowwise: 
      V1    V2    V3    V4  prod
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl>
 1     1     5     4     4    80
 2     6     6     6     5  1080
 3     1     5     4     5   100
 4     6     6     3     2   216
 5     3     1     3     6    54
 6     3     6     2     2    72
 7     5     2     4     2    80
 8     1     4     6     2    48
 9     6     4     6     3   432
10     5     5     5     3   375
# ... with 90 more rows
```